# how to avoid output foreach error?

Tags: php, foreach

In this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), it mentions:

> ***foreach*** does not support the ability to suppress error messages using '@'.

How do I avoid an output `foreach` error? I do not want see:

> **Warning**: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Is there a way to make an `if else` judgement?

Comment: It's simple. Just do not supply invalid arguments to `foreach`. Avoid errors, instead of suppressing them. Your code should not contain any `@` *at all*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before foreach check if variable contain array:

```
if (is_array($var))
{
   foreach...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to test if the array is empty, there won't be any error if it is.

Comment: Well foreach on an empty array doesn't raise an error. Am I crazy ? `$var = array(); foreach($var as $elem) echo 'A';` will not raise any error.

Comment: @Matthieu I mean "it works", thought you mean "this code wrong", sorry.

Answer (score 5):

prefix the variable with a (array) like this.

```
foreach( (array) $array_thats_not_an_array as $key => $value ){
    echo $key . ' ' . $value;
}
```

Comment: I find it more explicit to have a `if` block.

Comment: what will do your code, if `$array_thats_not_an_array` will contain Object? Resource? What if `$array_thats_not_an_array` contain wrong type because algorithm was coded with errors? Error will be muted and it will be more difficult to find.

Comment: Your absolutely right, i woud not use it in this kind of fasion. But he did not want to see a error. "I do not want see Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" ;)

Comment: Also this way will not work when you modify array by reference; `foreach ((array) $arr as &$val) $val += 2;` elements of array will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($array)) {
  foreach($array as $a) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: You should rather check that it's an array. If it's empty, there won't be any error so you don't need to test that.

Comment: @Matthieu: Isn't avoiding an error exactly what the poster asked for?

Comment: Yes that's my point, checking if the array is empty is useless, because even without your test there wouldn't be an error

Answer (score 0):

I used OZ's suggestion but got an error on the `is_array` test.

But adding a `@` before the name of the array to be tested worked a treat.

```
    if (is_array((@$errors))){
      foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
        <?php echo $error; ?>
        <br/>
      <?php endforeach;
    }
```

and yes I know using `@` is shoddy BUT I cannot get a tiny bit of inherited code working prettily.  I can either spend another hour to fix that to get round a "your var is not defined" or stick a `@` in and get the other things needed for a very ALFA version to share with a friend tomorrow. Oh and yes 11 pm and my brain is befuddled!

ATB Mr Grumpy
PS Big thanks to OZ_ for 95% of the solution!